# Using power shell to right a put method for SSRS API deployment for setting shareddataset

Tags: powershell

I want to use PowerShell to set shareddataset for a report using SSRS API.

I have already tried to use PowerShell to get shareddataset using SSRS API successfully. But failed to use put method.

**Success using get method:**

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

$Url = "http://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/DataSets"
`
`$Body = @{
Path ="/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key";
output_mode = "csv";
earliest_time = "-2d@d";
latest_time = "-1d@d";
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'GET' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -OutFile output.csv
```

**failed using put method:**

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

$Url = "http://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Reports(23a6af79-9de3-49cb-b66b-625d3ff3909b)/SharedDataSets"

$Body = @{
Id = "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6";
Name = "P_Calculate_Date_Default_Key";
Path = "/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key";
Type = "DataSet" ;
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method 'PUT'
```

Error returned is

> > The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

detailed error:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. At line:12 char:1 + Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method 'PU ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

I hope the put method could be working. I thought I was using the same way as the get method but it still failed.

I tried another way but still failed :

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Url = "http://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Reports(23a6af79-9de3-49cb-b66b-625d3ff3909b)/SharedDataSets"
$Body = @{

   Id = "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6"
  Name = "P_Calculate_Date_Default_Key"
  Path = "/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key"
  Type = "DataSet"

}| ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method PUT -ContentType "application/json" | Out-Null
```

Just for you to know that for the put method, i have already tested on postman and it works. So I guess currently it is only due to some logic in powershell side inconsistent.

in postman I put the link as : 
http://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Reports(23a6af79-9de3-49cb-b66b-625d3ff3909b)/SharedDataSets

Body as :

```
[
  {
      "Id": "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6",
      "Name": "P_Calculate_Date_Default_Key",
      "Path": "/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key",
      "Type": "DataSet"
  }
]
```

I tried your recommendation and it shows below , I have added it below all:
    PS C:\Users\dkx42a8adm> $Cred = Get-Credential
    $Url = "http://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Reports(23a6af79-9de3-49cb-b66b-625d3ff3909b)/SharedDataSets"
    $Body = @{

```
   Id = "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6"
  Name = "P_Calculate_Date_Default_Key"
  Path = "/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key"
  Type = "DataSet"

}| ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output $Body

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method PUT -ContentType "application/json" 

$error[0]|format-list -force
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
{
"Path":  "/Shared_data_sets/P_Calculate_date_Default_key",
"Name":  "P_Calculate_Date_Default_Key",
"Id":  "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6",
"Type":  "DataSet"
}
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:14 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method PUT     ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                           at     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
    TargetObject          : System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:     (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
    ErrorDetails          : 
    InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
    ScriptStackTrace      : at , : line 14
    PipelineIterationInfo : {}
    PSMessageDetails      :

Comment: sorry please kindly ignore the "  `  ". It seems to be with some mistake when I was editing this question.

Comment: Please expand on "Failed". Do you get an error or does it just not do anything?

Comment: Dear Nick,  the error is shown as below: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:12 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method 'PU ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Please edit your original question and put it in there.

Comment: In the example here https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/blob/master/APISamples/powershell/powershellSamples.ps1 the body is defined differently. Carefully compare your `$body` to the examples `$payload`. i.e. the sample has a `| ConvertTo-Json` in it and yours doesn't

Comment: Dear Nick, Thanks a lot for your quick reply.  But I think the example is somehow a little different from my intense. I was meaning to update the shareddataset of a report .  About you said to edit my orginal question, do you mean I should recreate a new question? because I did not find anywhere I can edit this question again.

Comment: With regards to editing the question, I've edited it and added it for you. Are you saying you don't have an "edit" option at the bottom of the question?

Comment: Hi Nick , I found it now. and I have updated my qustion. About your proposal , I tried but still get the same error.

Comment: With regards to the samples. Yes the samples are doing different operations to what you want but they show a sample of the correct way to build the body of the request.  Usually what we do now, is you edit your question and add the new code that you tried.

Comment: Hi Nick , I just added the new code.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have updated a littl in the question that for the put method I tested on postman and it worked so I guess the only problem now is in powershell side.

Comment: If you take another look at the sample you'll note that the attribute names are in quotes so try `"Id" = "935be257-5a65-4c0d-b372-d5a6a188daf6"` etc.

Comment: Hi Nick, I just tried and it suffered same error. Honstly, I don't think it is due to this reason because for the get method , it works fine.

Comment: I had assumed that the GET ignored your payload but I see that it must be using it, so you're probably right, the payload syntax is probably fine. Is there any additional JSON _returned_ from the `PUT` that may give you a more useful error message?

Comment: The other thing you could do is ouput `$Body` directly as a string and confirm that it looks exactly like the body in Postman

Comment: You could also remove the ` | Out-Null` part from your rest call and see if there is any reponse

Comment: Hi nick, I removed 'Out-Null 'it still returns below error:Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:12 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Credential $Cred -Body $body -Method PUT ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: About you mentioned $Body to directly as a string. Could you please kindly suggest detailed about how it would work ?

Comment: Add `Write-Output $Body`. I note when I test that it doesn't surround it with square brackets (makes it a single JSON array element)

Comment: Hi Nick, I have not used this before . Is that possible for you to help provide a short example for me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: In your existing powershell script, _before_ the line `Invoke-RestMethod`, add the line `Write-Output $Body`. Then run your script and it should display the JSON body

Comment: Basically HTTP 400 means "I don't understand your message". Either we get more detail or we work out the correct message format by trial and error. Another way to get more detail is to also add this to the end of your powershell script: `$error[0]|format-list -force`. This will display more error detail if there is any, although it might be useless stack trace rather than any more info from the web service

Comment: Hi Nick, I have tried your recommendation and I have added all of the execution log & error log in the question. Could you please kindly check it ? Thanks a lot !